# How to save only those packets using 80 port for communication in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I am new with wire shark software and want to know that how to save those packets which use 80 port for communication?

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, "packets which use 80 port", in the filter box:

tcp.port == 80 || udp.port == 80

(though I don't think you'll ever see much udp on this port)

Then, "how to save those packets":

menu > file > export specified packets

...by default this will save the packets currently displayed by the applied filter.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for a [capture filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters):
port 80

Add a capture filter:
go to 
[Capture](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseCaptureMenuSection.html)
[Options](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureOptions.html)
enter "port 80" (without quotes) in the capture filter input field (the input field will become green when you enter a valid string)
hit start